# Android calling intent function

Tags: android

*In this sample code StartActivity is giving error, if i use this in another class with extends Activity it doies not. Is there anyway i can call Intent in the class given below ??*

```
public class animation extends View{
......................................................
 Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.mypackage.na.SELECT");
 startActivity(openStartingPoint); 
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown? And where do you call startActivity() from? Please be more specific describing your question.

Comment: startActivity() should be called from a method not from the class container, and it is a method of the Context class, from which View is not an ancestor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class that extends [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) or a refrence to a `Context` in order to start a new `Activity`. In your case to start an Activity from a class that extends `View` you could use the `Context` of that `View`:

```
    getContext().startActivity(new Intent("com.mypackage.na.SELECT"));
```

Answer (score 2):

[startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) is a method of the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class. So you'll need an objects which extends the Context class like for example the Activity class does. So to call the method you have to pass a Context object into the your animation class.

Answer (score 0):

startActivity() always takes an object which extends one context class as exactlt said by above. So you need to pass one object argument for startActivity() and the next class name.